# Showing items in Form Array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular-formbuilder

I need to show users' names and a list of their courses. Different users have different numbers of courses. Thus, I am trying [Angular Form Array](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/).

Here is my .ts:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  courses: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({          
      name: [''],     
    })
  ]),
});

get courses() {
  return this.form.controls["courses"] as FormArray;
}
```

and my .html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="mb-3">
     <label>Name</label>
     <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>                    
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
     <label>Courses</label>                    
     <div formArrayName="courses">
       <div *ngFor="let course of courses.controls; let i = index">
         <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
         </div>                                                                                                       
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>      
</form>
```

The problem is that a user has two courses but only one of the courses is shown! Does anyone know what is the problem?

P.s. Happy new year :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure each `course` instance will require a `FormGroup` instance in the `courses` array.

```
for (let course of this.data.courses) {
  let courseFormGroup = this.newCourseFromGroup();
  courseFormGroup.patchValue(course);

  this.courses.push(courseFormGroup);
}
```

To avoid code duplication in creating a `Course` FormGroup, suggest creating a function as below:

```
newCourseFromGroup() {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
  });
}
```

Also, concerned that your current code will add a `FormGroup` instance into the `courses` `FormArray`. This will result an additional `FormGroup` instance would be added if you push the `FormGroup` as my proposed code.

Thus, you should only initialize the `FormArray` by adding a default `FormGroup` for `courses` `FormArray` if the *data* doesn't exist as below:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  courses: this.fb.array([]),
});

if (this.data) {
  for (let course of this.data.courses) {
    let courseFormGroup = this.newCourseFromGroup();
    courseFormGroup.patchValue(course);

    this.courses.push(courseFormGroup);
  }
} else {
  this.addCourse();
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e6sdch?file=src%2Fmain.ts)